# Rust protection on galvanized steel water tank

Tags: welding, rust-proofing

I got a custom water tank from galvanized steel done in a workshop for my campervan. But its welding points are exposed and probably will rust. It is mainly for kitchen and shower water, not for drinking.

What would be the most food safe option to protect weld points from rust? I'm thinking about covering the areas with a thin layer of food grade epoxy. Would that work?

Comment: There are (allegedly) food-safe cold galvanizing sprays. [This one](https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/00044305) for example.

Comment: May have been more cost effective in stainless...

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already determined that galvanized steel is an appropriate material for the purpose, take or send the tank to a hot-dip galvanizing plant to have it re-dipped to galvanize the welds. Then it will be fully galvanized and not prone to rusting.

The [American Galvanizers Association](https://galvanizeit.org/about-aga/galvanizer-locations) has a search page to find a galvanizer near you.